# Two Android App with SalesForce Sdk conflicting on single device

Tags: java, android, salesforce

I have two android app with the SalesForce SDK integrated, but the case is if I installed one app in mobile and I launched another then it's SalesForce login page is not getting appeared.

Please give me solution or tell me the reason why it is happening if anyone know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "account_type" tag in your strings.xml

It will avoid conflict of two sales force sdk in single device.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the session ID is active for Salesforce.

**SalesForce OAuth2 Ongoing Authorization** flow documentation says

> 1. The customer opens a mobile app.
> 2. If the session ID is active, the app starts immediately. If the session ID is stale, the app uses the refresh token from its initial authorization to get an updated session ID.
> 3. The app starts.

Please read the [Salesforce OAuth2 Authentication Flow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/mobile_sdk_introduction/units/mobilesdk_intro_security) for details.